# A question about when to close mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

A question about when to close mysql query.

Hello, I have two cases to decide whether I should close the mysql query.

First case, I know I should close this query.

But for the second case, should I also close the query as the same as the first case?

first case

```
~code
$result = $conn->query($query);
    if(!$result) {
        die("Invalid");
    }
    $rows = $result->num_rows;
    $password = sanitizeString($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
            $result->data_seek($i);
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $salt1 = $row['1'];
            $salt2 = $row['2'];
            $hashtoken = $row['pass'];
            $admin = $row['username'];
            $result->close(); // here
        }
```

second case

```
                $query = "INSERT INTO storage (name, content) VALUES ('$file_name', '$content')";
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                if (!$result) {
                    die("error");
                } else {
                    echo "Uploaded! <br>";
                }
                $result->close(); // here
```

Comment: More importantly though is why in the first code are you using `data_seek()` etc. to read rows sequentially?

Comment: More importantly still, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: You "should" close used queries/result sets since you don't need them anymore and can release any resources/information about them, but it is kinda not required per se since PHP will close all the queries at the end of the script anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to close mysql connection after every request.

On your given first case you should close your mysql connection  after end of for syntax.

Your second case is fine.

Comment: what do you mean by fine? first case, close is mandatory, but second case, i do not have to close it?